# Compose components labeled as unresolved references after building

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have an almost brand-new project, following official Android Developers course.

MainActivity.kt:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.junclabs.diceroller.ui.theme.DiceRollerTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            DiceRollerTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    DiceRollerApp()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun DiceRollerApp() {
    DiceWithButtonAndImage(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center)
    )
}

@Composable
fun DiceWithButtonAndImage(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    var result by remember { mutableStateOf(1) }
    Column(modifier = modifier, horizontalAlignment = CenterHorizontally) {
        Image(painter = painterResource(id = imageResource), contentDescription = result.toString())
        val imageResource =
            when (result) {
                1 -> R.drawable.dice_1
                2 -> R.drawable.dice_2
                3 -> R.drawable.dice_3
                4 -> R.drawable.dice_4
                5 -> R.drawable.dice_5
                else -> R.drawable.dice_6
            }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Button(onClick = { result = (1..6).random() }) {
            Text(stringResource(R.string.roll))
        }
    }
}
```

build.gradle.kts (:app):

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.junclabs.diceroller"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.junclabs.diceroller"
        minSdk = 25
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.5.4")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics:1.5.4")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.5.4")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.2")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}
```

And those are the errors:
[image: unresolved references]

Comment: Are the errors for all compose related components or for some only? Also, did you try adding imports?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your BOM with this version:

```
implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.01')
```

Yours is out-of-date.

Comment: If I use this, the implementation is marked as an unresolved reference, and the text in parenthesis shows "Too many characters in a character literal ''androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.01''